# WHEN to call restore_error_handler()?

Tags: php, exception, error-handling

This has bugged me for some time.

When I call `set_error_handler()`, errors and warnings and notices are routed to my handler, and when i call `restore_error_handler()`, my previously defined handler is restored.  But what happens when an `exception` is thrown before `restore_error_handler()` is called?

I have the following defined within a class:

```
function do_something() {
    set_error_handler([$this, 'convert_errors_to_exceptions']);

    //stuff that may trigger error, e.g.
    trigger_error('testing an error');

    //will this actually ever be called?
    restore_error_handler();
}


public function convert_errors_to_exceptions($num, $message, $file, $line) {
    //if error reporting turned off
    if (!(error_reporting() & $num)) return false;
    //convert to exception - then what happens?
    throw new Exception("Error: $message in $file on line $line");
    return true;
}
```

Will `restore_error_handler()` ever be called if an `error` is triggered?  And do I have to call `restore_error_handler()` immediately prior to throwing the `exception` if I want my previous handler to actually handle the `exception` itself?

Cart/horse problems!

Comment: `trigger_error(..)` does not `exit()` or `return` so `//will this actually ever be called?
    restore_error_handler();` should be executed take a look [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/415af54ef084cfd6a51fda5b840d0676cfabbc40)

Comment: Yes, but my custom error handler throws an exception (which does exit) - that's the point of my question.

Comment: oh yes offcource.. what is the main goal you want to restore the defualt error handle annyway by the way?

Comment: Well, my previous handler was not the default, but rather also a custom handler, with specific handling/logging of notices and warnings, etc. I want to ensure my previous custom handler is restored once the exception is thrown from my updated handler.  And I don't want to duplicate code from the old handler to the new.

Comment: what if you combine the two custom error handlers into one custom error handler?

Comment: Was hoping to avoid having to do that - I want to keep them separate - thus the use of `set_error_handler`. In my case, I don't want to refactor my framework-level error handler.  The use case for my secondary handler is very specific.